# Using Java Swing to calculate the number of weeks between a start date and end date

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

Title says it all, I need to be able to have a user inputted start date and end date in the form of month/day, and be able to calculate the number of weeks in between.  I wanted to use JList to solve this, but it seems like JList only works with strings.

What Swing function would I use, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can use {[jcalendar(http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/)} and for date arithmetic [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: `"but it seems like JList only works with strings"` --- This is not true at all since a JList can work with *any* class type you desire, including a Date. You just have to give it a try.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how can i make links :( i always forget

Comment: @nachokk square brackets for the link name then parenthesis for link address.  [ link name ] ( http://link address ) without the spaces

Comment: +1 for [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't refer to Swing.

Use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for your purposes

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.PeriodType;

....
    public static Map<Integer, String> getDateTimeDiffMap(String dateA, String dateB) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Map<Integer,String> out = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

    long timeInMillA = 0;
    long timeInMillB = 0;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT); 

    Date convertedDateA;
    Date convertedDateB;

    try {
    convertedDateA = dateFormat.parse(dateA);           
    cal.setTime(convertedDateA);
    timeInMillA = cal.getTimeInMillis();


    convertedDateB = dateFormat.parse(dateB);           
    cal.setTime(convertedDateB);
    timeInMillB = cal.getTimeInMillis();

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 


    LocalDateTime startA = new LocalDateTime(timeInMillA);
    LocalDateTime startB = new LocalDateTime(timeInMillB);

    Period difference = new Period(startA, startB, PeriodType.days());
    int day = difference.getDays();

    difference = new Period(startA, startB, PeriodType.months());
    int month = difference.getMonths();

    difference = new Period(startA, startB, PeriodType.years());
    int year = difference.getYears();

    difference = new Period(startA, startB, PeriodType.weeks());
    int week = difference.getWeeks();

    difference = new Period(startA, startB, PeriodType.hours());
    int hour = difference.getHours();

    difference = new Period(startA, startB, PeriodType.minutes());
    long min = difference.getMinutes();

    difference = new Period(startA, startB, PeriodType.seconds());
    long sec = difference.getSeconds();

    //difference = new Period(startA, startB, PeriodType.millis());
    long mili = timeInMillB - timeInMillA;  


    out.put(7, mili + "");
    out.put(6, sec + "");
    out.put(5, min + "");
    out.put(4, hour + "");
    out.put(3, day + "");
    out.put(2, week + "");
    out.put(1, month + "");
    out.put(0, year + "");      

    return out;
}
```

For example for "01-09-2012 20:9:01", "01-10-2012 20:9:01" I get output:

```
year=0;
month = 1;
day=30;
hour=720;
...
```